# How do I use the new launchUrl() method with a "mailto:" link?

Tags: flutter, dart, mailto, email-client, url-launcher

I have a little link in my app that says "Send us an e-mail". When you click it, I want the default email app to open, with an email started to our email address. I used to make it do exactly that with the `launch()` method in the `url_launcher` package like this:

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as url;

Future<bool?> pressedSendUsEmail() async {
  bool? success;
  try {
    print('Pressed Send us an e-mail...');
    success = await url.launch('mailto:our.email@gmail.com');  // Works like a charm...
    print('success is $success');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Caught an error in Send us an e-mail!');
    print('e is: ${e.toString()}');
  }
  return success;
}
```

But now, I get a warning saying `launch()` is deprecated! I should use `launchUrl()` instead. But `launchUrl()` doesn't take a String argument, it takes a Uri argument... and I don't know how to write this Uri correctly, so that it does what I want! I tried:

```dart
  success = await url.launchUrl(Uri(path: 'mailto:our.email@gmail.com'));
```

but that throws an error, because it can't interpret the ":" character. I've tried:

```dart
  success = await url.launchUrl(
    Uri.https('mailto:our.email@gmail.com', ''),
  );
```

and that launches the link, but in the browser... and it doesn't start up an e-mail to the pre-printed address. I tried adding:

```dart
  success = await url.launchUrl(
    Uri.https('mailto:our.email@gmail.com', ''),
    mode: url.LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  );
```

and that gives me an option of which external app to open the link with, but unfortunately, only browser apps are listed... not the email app!

How should I write my command to make the `launchUrl()` just do exactly what the old `launch()` did?? Most grateful for help!

---

Edit:

After that question was satisfactorily answered below, I now have a follow-up qn:

In another part of the app, there is a place where the user can type in a link, and I used to launch it with `launch()`... Is there a simple way to do that, as well?

Because in that case, I don't know if the link is gonna be a http or a https or indeed a mailto:!... and I would prefer not having to write lots of code to find that out! I just want it to try and launch the link exactly the way it's written, and so long as it's written correctly, it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the service already built-in to `Uri`...

```
void _sendEmail(){
    final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
        scheme: 'mailto',
        path: 'our.email@gmail.com',
        queryParameters: {
            'subject': 'CallOut user Profile',
            'body': widget.userModel?.username ?? ''
        },
    );
    launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);
}
```

Comment: Ooooh, now I get it!  Nice work, thank you! If only you had been a bit clearer a bit earlier, I wouldn't have marked that other answer as the correct one.  (Although it also did the job!)

Comment: But now, I have a follow-up qn!: In another part of the app, there is a place where the user can type in a link, and I used to launch it with `launch()`... Do you have a simple way to do that, as well? Because in that case, I don't know if the link is gonna be a `http` or a `https` or indeed a `mailto:`!... and I would prefer not having to write lots of code to find that out!

Comment: You can certainly Uri.parse(aString) to get the components.

Comment: That is a wonderful, universal solution to all my problems!  Let's update question and answer with this.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
void _sendEmail(){
   final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
     scheme: 'mailto',
     path: 'our.email@gmail.com',
     queryParameters: {
      'subject': 'CallOut user Profile',
      'body': widget.userModel?.username ?? ''
     },
    );
   launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);
}
```

Comment: Looks good!... I wasn't planning to add any subject or body, but then I guess I can just use this without the whole `query:` part? 

Comment: remove if you don't need it

Comment: Uh, queryParameters can be given a Map<String,String> and it just does the right thing.  Your whole "encodeQueryParameters" is completely redundant, and partially wrong.  Please remove.  See https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/Uri/queryParameters.html for details.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz , what is this "queryParameters" you're talking about? My AS doesn't find it in the `url_laucher` package or elsewhere! And the "query" property of the Uri above takes a String argument, and not a Map<String, String>...

Comment: And PS, the `encodeQueryParameters()` sub method in @XuannThucc's answer above works fine...

Comment: See my answer.  It's an argument to Uri!

Comment: I've seen it, and accepted it. You should change the wording, though! No need to refer to an "other answer" in your answer. People are only supposed to have to read ONE answer. @RandalSchwartz

Answer (score 1):

The built-in query builder only work correctly for http/https.

For anything else, the following should be used, otherwise you will have "+" instead of spaces:

```dart
String? encodeQueryParameters(Map<String, String> params) {
  return params.entries
      .map((MapEntry<String, String> e) =>
          '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
      .join('&');
}
///
void _sendEmail() {
  final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
    scheme: 'mailto',
    path: 'our.email@gmail.com',
    query: encodeQueryParameters({
      'subject': 'CallOut user Profile',
      'body': widget.userModel?.username ?? ''
    }),
  );
  launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);
}
```

Source: [url_launcher Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#encoding-urls)