# Flutter compose HTML mail with url_launcher

Tags: flutter

I have to send a mail like this:

```
final Uri url = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: '',
  query:
      'subject=Invitation&Body=Hi, Click <a href="https://google.com">here</a> to launch Google',
);
launchUrl(url);
```

How do I set the mail body to be in HTML (so that `here` is a link). Tried `IsHtml=true` and `IsHtmlBody=true`...

Comment: May be it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812591/how-do-i-use-the-new-launchurl-method-with-a-mailto-link

Comment: @AlexColoma, not really. The question is how to have the mail client see the body text as HTML. Now HTML <a href="https://google.com">here</a> is showing up as text...